# For $R$-modules $M,N$, what are sufficient conditions for $\operatorname{Supp}(M\otimes_R N)\subseteq \operatorname{Supp}(\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,N))$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, $M$ and $N$ be finitely generated $R$-modules. What additional conditions will ensure $\operatorname{Supp}(M\otimes_R N)\subseteq \operatorname{Supp}(\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,N))$?

Comment: Don't we have $\mathrm{supp}(M \otimes N)=\mathrm{supp}(M) \cap \mathrm{supp}(N)$? Have you considered the case that $R$ is local?

Comment: The reverse inclusion is true when $R$ is a commutative ring and $M$ and $N$ are finitely generated. I wanted to know when the above inclusion is true, under what conditions.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\Hom}{\operatorname{Hom}}$$\newcommand{\Supp}{\operatorname{Supp}}$$\newcommand{\Ass}{\operatorname{Ass}}$$\newcommand{\depth}{\operatorname{depth}}$$\newcommand{\ann}{\operatorname{ann}}$Assuming that $R$ is Noetherian, the same reasoning given in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/734767/115654) shows that $\Supp(M \otimes_R N) = \Supp(\Hom_R(M,N))$ iff $\depth(\ann M_p, N_p) = 0$ for every minimal element $p$ of $\Supp(M) \cap \Supp(N)$ iff the minimal elements of $\Supp(N) \cap \Supp(M)$ and $\Ass(N) \cap \Supp(M)$ coincide. One only needs to update the reasoning given there with the following facts:

1) $\Hom_R(M, N) = 0$ iff $\ann M$ contains a nonzerodivisor on $N$

2) $\Ass(\Hom_R(M,N)) = \Ass(N) \cap \Supp(M)$ (see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/417703)).